# How do you set up Popcorn.js to be compatible with jPlayer?

Tags: html, audio, jplayer, popcornjs

Popcorn.js typically requires a media element such as "video" or "audio", how do you use a jPlayer id with popcorn.js?

I currently have this:

```
     var slide2 = Popcorn("#jquery_jplayer_2").data("jPlayer").internal.audio.id);

     slide2.exec(6, function() { $('#slide2first').fadeIn(500); });
     slide2.exec(50, function() { $('#slide2second').fadeIn(500); });
     slide2.exec(53, function() { $('#slide2third').fadeIn(500); });
     slide2.exec(61, function() { $('#slide2fourth').fadeIn(500); });
     slide2.exec(67.5, function() { $('#slide2fifth').fadeIn(500); });
     slide2.exec(71, function() { $('#slide2sixth').fadeIn(500); });
```

Answer (score 0):

jPlayer might embed a Flash object, depending on your browser and supplied media, in which case you wouldn't have the HTML 5 audio element you need.. are you forcing jPlayer to use HTML?

Are you really sure it's necessary to use jPlayer in conjunction with Popcorn?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the "Popcorn jPlayer Player Plugin" :
http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-09-popcorn-video/

The plugin is shipped with the last jPlayer release, 2.2.0 as of September 13th, 2012.

I didn't try it, cause my project took another road. As I understand it, the goal would be to use Popcorn in non-HTML5 browsers as well as mobile browsers. However, it is explicitly written in the page above that "Due to limitations in Popcorn 1.3, IE6/7/8 will not work."

They do seem optimistic to offer another solution in the future.